# Resize figure to Axes Position in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure with a bar plot in it, I have removed all ticks and titles, so now only the bars themselves are shown. I'd like to have the figure shrink to the size of the bar plot.
I've tried the following:

```
set(gca,'Units', 'Pixels');  
set(gca,'XLim', [0.5 10.5],'YLim', [0 1],'Units', 'Pixels');
a=get(gca, 'Position');
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Pixels');
b=get(gcf,'Position');
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatioMode', 'manual', 'XLimMode', 'manual','YLimMode', 'manual')
set(gca, 'Position', [5,5,a(3),a(4)]);
set(gcf, 'Position', [10,10, a(3)+10,a(4)+10]);
```

This however doesn't work. after some investigations I found that the main problem is that the axes don't snap to the axis size.
Any way to solve this without calculating the size of every plot in the figure?
I want to decrease the blank areas around the plot below:
[image: original figure]
this is the figure after running my code, still a lot of space remains, this is because this is the size of the axes:

[image: figure after code has run]

Thanks

edit: The problem stems from axes size as illustrated by the image below, upper picture is with `DataAspectRatio` set to `[1 1 1]` and lower picture without (automatic mode). note that the axes size doesn't change (noted by black squares)
*there is some change due to opening plot tools, which docks the figure.
[image: figure with manual aspect ratio]
[image: figure with automatic aspect ratio]

Comment: Can you post a sample plot and show what areas you wish to "shrink" in it?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
f = figure;

% generate bar
y = [75.995,91.972,105.711,123.203,131.669,...
       150.697,179.323,203.212,226.505,249.633,281.422];
bar(y);
% end of graph  

axis tight;
allAx = findall(f,'type','axes');
pa = get(gca, 'Position');
pf = get(f, 'Position');
% change shape of the figure to match                                                                                         
% xsize(figure)/yszie(figure) = xsize(axis)/ysize(axis)                                                                       
pf(4) = ((pf(3)-pf(1))*pa(4)+pa(2)*(pf(1)-pf(3))+pf(2)*pa(3)-pa(1)*pf(2))/(pa(3)-pa(1));
set(allAx, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0, 0, 1, 1]);
set(f, 'Position', pf);
```

Comment: It  works but skews the plot, so that I get long rectangles instead of squares. I want x and y to have the same aspect ratio

Comment: I added figure rescale to the answerer.

Comment: This actually makes things worse. Perhaps I wasn't clear before but the problem is with the axes not the figure. This is a result of making the `DataAspectRatio` `[1 1 1]`, this keeps the axes in the same size but changes the axis. I will add a picture to the question to hopefully make this clearer.